# How do you describe if two sets of numbers are described by the same inequality (of >,<,=)?

Tags: inequality

Is there a mathematically rigorous way to say that the symbol comparing a and b is the same as the symbol comparing c and d (specifically <,>, and =)?

Presumably, one could say that their differences have the same sign, but this leaves out the means to say that there are both equal to each other, at least to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the sign function i.e.

sgn $(a-b)=$sgn $(c-d)$.

Comment: And this works in the case $a = b$ or $c = d$, as according to the usual definition, $\operatorname{sgn}(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Words are just as mathematically rigorous as symbols, and often easier to understand. You could say

> $a-b$ and $c-d$ have the same sign

(with an added phrase taking $0$ into account if you wish, although that's not strictly necessary).

If you need this often in something you are writing you could invent a symbol for it. C++ uses the symbol $<=>$ for the [three way comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison).

.